# Method scrolled on scrollDispatcher Angular Material always return undefined

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material

I am trying to use ScrollingModule from '@angular/cdk/scrolling', but with the scrolled() method I am not getting the expected result, this is my code:

**My imports**

```
import { CdkScrollable, ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

**Dependency Injection**

```
constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher){}
```

**Code**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((event: CdkScrollable) => {      
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

**Expected**

> Object type CdkScrollable

**Getting**

> Undefined

I read the bibliography and some articles and I think that my code is fine, I don't understand what is wrong.

**Issue replicated here**
https://github.com/alcampospalacios/ScrollingDistpachProblem

Comment: Did you import the `ScrollDispatchModule` into your module?

Comment: Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-scroll-dispatcher

Comment: @Vishnudev ScrollDispatchModule has been deprecated, it is no longer necessary.

Comment: You did not mention the version of angular you were using. I assumed it is older one.

Comment: @Vishnudev Should be imported instead ScrollingModule and i have imported.

Comment: Can you add your HTML setup.

Comment: @Vishnudev My fault sorry i am using angular 10, thanks for your replies any idea?

Comment: @Vishnudev I don't have registered the html event with cdkScrollable because according to Angular material they say: Returns an observable that emits an event whenever any of the registered Scrollable references **(or window, document, or body)** fire a scrolled event. Can provide a time in ms to override the default "throttle" time. So automaticly should be fired the event when i do scroll

Comment: Check [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddw27x?file=src/app/app.component.ts), try scrolling inside the scrollable div and then check the body scroll. As said in the docs it might return void for unregistered scrollable elements.

Comment: @Vishnudev I see your example and then I wonder, **window, document, or body** are not registered scrollable events?? And if not how I can make it registered?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve out of this?

Comment: They are registered that's why you are at least getting undefined when you scroll **window, body**, but they are not **CdkScrollable**

Answer (score 1):

The window is scrolling, not the `<p>` where you set the `cdkScrollable` on. As you can see the [API](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api) clearly states that the `Observable` can return a `CdkScrollable | void`. In the case that a `CdkScrollable` does not scroll, it will return `void`.

In your example you can see that the entire body is scrolling. You need to make your structure so that only the inner element scrolls

Comment: So, the **window, document or body** are not a registered scrollable event?

Comment: they are not a `CdkScrollable`, because that's a directive you place on an element